# trying to save script in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, anaconda, save, jupyter

I have written a lot of code in jupyter noteboook and I will save it when I am finished. However, when I exit out and I open up the specific program in jupyter I notice that I have to run every single line in order for the code to continue working. This is a lengthy task. I have to first run all of the import functions and then remember which code comes first so that it will operate in a orderly fashion. Is there a way that I can prevent this from happening? Is there a way that I can save the code in jupyter notebook and when I open it again I can just run it without having to go to each and every cell and hit the run function?

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is there even a way to save code in anaconda? I tend to use jupyter just because I cannot even find a way to save in anaconda.

Comment: What do you mean by "in anaconda"

Comment: Sorry let me clarify.. I mean how do I save code inside ipython.I was wondering if there is a way that you can save code inside the anaconda terminal when you go to ipython